# how to connect 4 laptops to one monitor

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to connect video from 4 laptops to a big screen monitor and be able switch from one to another easily without having to connect and disconnect cables.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Unless your monitor supports 4 inputs, which most don't, you'll likely need a switch.

Presuming your laptops all have Mini Displayport or Thunderbolt out, [this will work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008ABLBWW).

Comment: How about an [HDMI switcher](http://www.amazon.com/Etekcity%C2%AE-Switcher-Supports-Wireless-Performance/dp/B00B2CGUPY/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1414677353&sr=8-7&keywords=hdmi+switcher), it's far cheaper?

Comment: Oops, apparently I missed the word "video" in OP's question.

Thanks dude.